# If condition based on tail and grep commands in Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell

I want to write an if condition in Shell script something like this:

```
if[ tail -10f logFile | grep -q "RUNNING" ]
```

So the idea is I have restarted my server and want to perform some action only after the server is started up(RUNNING). So I want to continuously tail the log and check if the server is in RUNNING mode again.

The issue with the above approach is it does not exits even after the server is RUNNING and goes into infinite loop. No code in if or else is printed.

Answer (score 1):

What about?

```
while [ $(tail -10 logFile | grep -c RUNNING) -eq 0 ]; do sleep 1; done
```

Comment: And if 11 lines were logged while you were sleeping?

Comment: Instead of `[ $(...) -eq 0 ]`, you could use `while ! tail [...] | grep -q RUNNING; do`, i.e., use the exit status directly.